# Extract title text from href with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a simple script to extract plain text from links titles but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://livestream.com/watch/browse/lifestyle/live')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
titl = soup.find_all("div", class_= 'owner_name_container ellipsis')
print(titl)
```

The output is:

```
[<div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/11436227">Karbala Satellite Channel</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/2064453">Obieqtivi TV</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/1257164">The AV Company</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/75381">Condo Hotels Playa del Carmen</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/3320102">Al Kawn Radio &amp; TV</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/26764475">Z1 Televizija</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/11436227">Karbala Satellite Channel</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/4237681">TVmos.tv</a>
</div>, <div class="owner_name_container ellipsis">
      on <a class="owner_name" href="/accounts/3673755">TVTEC</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? It's got the basics covered pretty nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `.text` on the element. In this case the text from each `<a>` tag in the `div` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://livestream.com/watch/browse/lifestyle/live')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
titl = soup.find_all("div", class_= 'owner_name_container ellipsis')

for each in titl:
    print(each.find('a').text)
```

**Output:**

```
Obieqtivi TV
Karbala Satellite Channel
The AV Company
Condo Hotels Playa del Carmen
Al Kawn Radio & TV
Lake Tahoe TV
...
```